# User Login with Staff and Customers MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I finally got permission to redesign our database (yay, everybody cheer)!

One of the problems that I need to overcome is user login.

The way the database is currently designed, there is a `User` table, with a 1:n relationship to `UserStaff` (user can have multiple staff - think of a manager). There is also a completely unrelated `Customer` table.

I need to create a table to consolidate the login so that all of these people (`User`, `UserStaff`, and `Customer`) can login to the same area, but each of these tables above has completely different information inside and different relationships to data.

How/where should I start moving things around to get this to work?

Comment: No. They are a separate entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "Login" table containing "loginID", "email", and "password" fields.  Each of the other tables (User, UserStaff, Customer) would also contain the "loginID" field.  Then at login-time you could SELECT from the login table, and (left) JOIN on loginID to the other tables to get your user's data.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is this (without the tables filled in with fields) what you're saying? http://cl.ly/2Z1Q0I3N0z031T3Y360L/database.bmp